# how to visualise/debug an imagemap?

Tags: html, imagemap

I'm dynamically generating an imagemap for a chart tool I have.

I was hoping to be able to set a border or color on the area tags so I could check everything was being generated with the right coords, but a little research shows this is not possible.

So whats the easiest way to check my image map is correct? Are there any browser tools which will "visualise" the areas?

Answer (score 7):

What about using JavaScript (and jQuery) to test it?

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

This plugin will highlight image map areas.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/) for that:

- Right-click your image and choose "Inspect Element with FireBug"
- In the HTML tab of Firebug, the `image` tag is highlighted: locate and expand the associated `map` tag, which usually is right after it
- You can now place your mouse over each `area` tags to see them highlighted over your image

Answer (score 6):

One way to visualize an area tag in Chrome is to add a `tabindex` to the `area` tag(s) you want to see, and then click or tab to it.  Chrome will nicely highlight the actual outline of the clickable area.

This solution unfortunately doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

[Image Map Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ime/) is a plug-in for Firefox. It is the best tool I have found so far, makes creating, inspecting, and editing image maps very easy.

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome you can select the area of the image map and click on the three little dots
to the left and then select "focus"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Never thought I would ever say that, but this is one of the few cases where Dreamweaver could be helpful. You'll have an interface, you will be able to work with anchor points and set your imagemap easily.