# What would be a good approach to creating a clickable menu from a blueprint where rooms are buttons?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a pdf that is a blueprint layout of a building.  I want to create a menu in phonegap somehow so that you can click on each room to get information.  The end product will be a phonegap application.  What libraries should I look in to to make this clickable menu with strangely shaped buttons and whatnot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642912/i-need-to-see-an-html-image-map-area