# Polygon Map with Links not working in IE or Edge

Tags: html

I have a polygon map setup that works fine with Chrome but not with IE or Edge. In those browsers only a couple of the links actually work. Here's my code:

```
<img src="Map for Web - Master - Effective 03-16-16.jpg" width="1126" height="718" alt="Territory Map" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">`<area shape="poly" coords="1005, 313, 1019, 315, 1022, 291, 1090, 258, 1071, 234, 1119, 161, 1076, 104,
 1056, 109, 1047, 131, 1033, 175, 1002, 188, 1017, 271, 985, 274, 994, 289, 993, 304" 
 href="../contact/49 Manning and Associates.html" alt="Manning and Associates"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="914, 341, 914, 352, 934, 345, 943, 352, 953, 350, 964, 355, 962, 366, 979, 375, 995, 398, 1021,
314, 1002, 315, 994, 305, 995, 289, 983, 273, 943, 280, 945, 336" href="../contact/50 Power Component Sales.html"  alt="Power Component Sales"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="706, 593, 722, 594, 763, 592, 771, 583, 766, 571, 815, 569, 818, 550, 902, 555, 909, 540, 851,
466, 830, 466, 881, 425, 752, 429, 751, 436, 727, 433, 721, 440, 717, 442, 710, 435, 619, 432, 618, 504, 629, 510, 628,
517, 689, 521, 693, 535, 679, 568, 718, 570, 718, 580" href="../contact/51 Clifford Sales.html" alt="Clifford Sales"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="456, 256, 555, 270, 564, 278, 571, 274, 591, 285, 602, 331, 675, 334, 685, 341, 695, 344,
707, 355, 761, 356, 761, 303, 755, 286, 755, 262, 766, 215, 826, 189, 815, 182, 799, 182, 798, 174, 775, 178, 771,
184, 761, 183, 753, 175, 738, 176, 759, 160, 745, 158, 725, 174, 700, 180, 703, 174, 678, 181, 717, 148, 661, 132,
653, 135, 637, 128, 631, 113, 626, 120, 476, 107" href="../contact/52 Industrial Component Sales.html" alt="Industrial Component Sales"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="530, 111, 628, 121, 629, 112, 631, 95, 631, 27, 655, 1, 539, 1" 
href="../contact/73 Techno-Rep.html" alt="Techno-Rep"/>
</map>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It could be the spaces in the URLs

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. The really strange thing is a couple of the links work but only in part of the area they are supposed to work in, whereas most of the links don't work at all.

Comment: Regarding the areas you can preview them using firebug - check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998866/how-to-visualise-debug-an-imagemap#answer-22639732 as of the links which of them exactly work and which don't?

Comment: I didn't include the full code as it is very large. Here is the only portion that fully works in IE: <area shape="poly" coords="309, 525, 333, 387, 237, 365, 271, 242, 92, 175, 89, 185, 73, 207, 67, 247, 87, 380, 143, 455, 188, 469, 261, 517" href="../contact/62 Pac West Marketing.html" alt="Pac West Marketing"/>
A few other areas only work around the edges or some other portion.